# Installing Sql Server Integration Services In Visual Studio As Plugin

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I ve looked around on Google for a while now without any joy.

I have SSIS at work and need it at home - I ve tried installing / uni stalling SQL server with no joy

Does anyone have a link to details of how to install?

This should be easy!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I definately agree with Faiz that you should use a virtual machine at home for occassional work-from-home development.  However, the VHD he mentioned is only good for 30 days and won't help you if you intend to work from home beyond 30 days.  If you have the option of connecting to your work machine via VPN And using remote desktop to work from home, then I recommend doing it.  Otherwise, you will probably have to duplicate many of your work databases at home and that is generally a very bad practice -- particularly if there is any customer-sensitive data in the databases.

If you still want to install SQL Server on your home machine, then can you provide more details on what doesn't work?

EDIT: Based on your comment, it sounds like your templates are missing or have a problem.  Below are a couple possible solutions.  Please note this is basically a summary of the comments listed on [this blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815093817/http://geekswithblogs.net/ehammersley/archive/2005/11/08/59451.aspx).  Also, solution 6 resolved a problem one of my team members had since he installed VS 2008 for Testers as well and chose the wrong team profile when he started using VS 2008.

1. Run the following at the command line:

   devenv /installvstemplates
2. Open the Options window in Visual Studio.
   Select Projects and Solutions.
   Change the Visual Studio user item template location to the folder where the standard templates are located ( C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates ).
3. Maybe it's a problem with the security properties of the "Microsoft Visual Studio 8" folder, which is set by the VS2005 Installer.  At first, "devenv /installvstemplates" doesn't work for me, but when I set "full control" for Administrator, "devenv /installvstemplates" repairs the project templates.
4. In de language drowdown in the new web site form the C# was twice in the list. When changing the language to the second item the missing templates appeared.
5. In my case the Administrator had "full control" of the folder.  After setting "full control" on the "Creator" and running "devenv /installvstemplates" - all my templates are there! Thaks a lot!
6. Tools -> Import/Export Settings -> Reset all settings -> Business Intelligence Settings.
7. I did manually go into the registry and delete everything under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0 and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0 before reinstalling. I don't know if this had any effect or not, but if you've unsuccessfully tried reinstalling before (and are okay editing your registry) it might be worth a shot.

If none of this helped, can you tell me if you have Business Intelligence Designers in the Tools -> Options screen?  It should be on the left with an expandable +/- sign.

Comment: What does not work is there is no Business Intelligence option when you go to Visual Studio -> New Project.

I have installed / uninstalled VS2008 a number of times with no success!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Virtual PC (VPC) for trying MSBI development at home. You need a machine with 1GB+ RAM and some 14GB free space. But it is the best way from my experience. No need to install and mess up with your Home PC's entertainment configuration. Download the Virtiual Hard Disk (VHD) for SQL Server 2005 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7b243252-acb7-451b-822b-df639443aeaf&displaylang=en).